# i want to run single o.s ,how to install ubuntu?

Tags: installation

I am running Windows 8 , and  I want to format the C drive and only use a single OS (Ubuntu) run in my computer.
I did install Ubuntu alongside Windows and it install and take more time so I shutdown the computer directly.

I opened Windows and it reduced my windows drive (C) size and not join again with C drive again try to install by selecting something else
and to delete c drive and install in c drive bt message display on screen

**No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu**

What do I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get rid of Windows do as Ed Manet said, the thing is that you have to be sure to repartition the booting hdd, it´s plain simple using the Ubuntu GUI while installing. I will recomend to NOT USE the manual partition method unless you know what are you doing.

Comment: i just repartition hdd ,you have  another way without repartititon

Comment: Sorry, but from what i read here "I am running Windows 8 , and I want to format the C drive and only use a single OS" you want to use just Ubuntu and forget about windows, so why bother in changing the drive C partition size?, just start the ubuntu installer, destroy the Windows partition and install the new OS from fresh use the guided installation and you should not have any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume that you downloaded the Ubuntu ISO image.

If you burned the image to a CD, you can boot to the CD and start the installation.
I'd recommend booting up to a live session off the CD first so that you can verify hardware compatibility before installing it.

Comment: i did verify hardware copmtibiltiy it's able to install it

Comment: Did you burn a CD from the ISO and boot up to it?